# insert data from mysql to array for phpexcel

Tags: php, mysql

Iam using PHPEXCEL class for export data and column chart from mysql to excel.

if i read from example in phpexcel use array

```
$sheet = array(

  array(
    '',
    '2010',
    '2011',
    '2012',
  ),
  array(
    'Q1',
    '12',
    '15',
    '21',
  ),
  array(
    'Q2',
    '56',
    '73',
    '86',
  ),
  array(
    'Q3',
    '52',
    '43',
    '66',
  ),
  array(
    'Q4',
    '52',
    '33',
    '46',
  )
);




foreach($sheet as $row => $columns) {
    foreach($columns as $column => $data) {
        $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row + 1, $data);
    }
}
?>
```

and i have mysql code :

```
$gdg = mysql_query("SELECT a.building_id, b.building_name FROM ticket_open a JOIN m_building b ON a.building_id = b.building_id GROUP BY b.building_id ORDER BY b.building_name ASC");
     while($hsldgd = mysql_fetch_array($gdg))                    
     {

        $gdgid = $hsldgd['building_id']; 
        $gdgname = $hsldgd['building_name'];

            $comp = mysql_query("SELECT ifnull(count(ticket_no),0) as jcomp FROM ticket_open WHERE STATUS = 'completed' AND 
                                 building_id = '$gdgid' ");
            $hslcomp = mysql_fetch_array($comp);    

            $ncomp = mysql_query("SELECT ifnull(count(ticket_no),0) as jncomp FROM ticket_open WHERE STATUS != 'completed' AND 
                                 building_id = '$gdgid'");
            $hslncomp = mysql_fetch_array($ncomp);  


        $jmlnot = $hslncomp['jncomp'];
        $jmlcomp = $hslcomp['jcomp'];
        $jmltick = $hslncomp['jncomp'] + $hslcomp['jcomp'] ;


        $sheet = array (
                array (

                $gdgname,
                $jmlnot,
                $jmlcomp,
                $jmltick,
                ),
            );


foreach($sheet as $row => $columns) {
foreach($columns as $column => $data) {
    $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row + 1, $data);
}
}
```

this code only read the last of data, not all data

please help me :)

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried to debug it and see if you get the correct result from the mysql part ? (fetching+building the array)

Comment: your issue is probably here -`$sheet = array`. every iteration of the while loop you override the variable.

Comment: also, you should never have a mysql query inside a loop,it is very inefficient

Comment: Thanks, @Gal, yes my problem at sheet = array...... i dont know why it can not looping, but if not insert to array it still looping  in mysql while...

Answer (score 0):

try the following code :

```
$sheet = array();
$gdg = mysql_query("SELECT a.building_id, b.building_name FROM ticket_open a JOIN m_building b ON a.building_id = b.building_id GROUP BY b.building_id ORDER BY b.building_name ASC");
     while($hsldgd = mysql_fetch_array($gdg))                    
     {

        $gdgid = $hsldgd['building_id']; 
        $gdgname = $hsldgd['building_name'];

            $comp = mysql_query("SELECT ifnull(count(ticket_no),0) as jcomp FROM ticket_open WHERE STATUS = 'completed' AND 
                                 building_id = '$gdgid' ");
            $hslcomp = mysql_fetch_array($comp);    

            $ncomp = mysql_query("SELECT ifnull(count(ticket_no),0) as jncomp FROM ticket_open WHERE STATUS != 'completed' AND 
                                 building_id = '$gdgid'");
            $hslncomp = mysql_fetch_array($ncomp);  


        $jmlnot = $hslncomp['jncomp'];
        $jmlcomp = $hslcomp['jcomp'];
        $jmltick = $hslncomp['jncomp'] + $hslcomp['jcomp'] ;


        $sheet[] = array (
                $gdgname,
                $jmlnot,
                $jmlcomp,
                $jmltick
                );

foreach($sheet as $row => $columns) {
foreach($columns as $column => $data) {
    $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row + 1, $data);
}
}
```

if that doesn't work please var_dump the `$sheet` variable.

P.S as I mentioned earlier you might want to fix your mysql queries.